# Creating a custom product type in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to create a custom product type using the class in woocommerce.
and after that, I have create a product with the class of custom product type.

Here is the code :

```
class WPFM_Online_Order_Food_Product extends WC_Product {

/**
 * The single instance of the class.
 *
 * @var self
 * @since  1.0.0
 */
private static $_instance = null;

/**
 * Allows for accessing single instance of class. Class should only be constructed once per call.
 *
 * @static
 * @return self Main instance.
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
public static function instance() {
    if (is_null(self::$_instance)) {
        self::$_instance = new self();
    }
    return self::$_instance;
}

/**
 * Constructor
 *
 * @param int|WC_Product|object $product Product ID, post object, or product object
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
public function __construct($product = null) {
    parent::__construct($product);
    $this->product_type = 'wpfm_food_product';
}

/**
 * Get internal type.
 *
 * @return string
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
public function get_type() {
    return 'wpfm_food_product';
}

/**
 * Get product id
 *
 * @return int
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
public function get_product_id() {
    return $this->get_id();
}
}
```

and add type in 'product_type_selector' hook:

```
add_filter('product_type_selector', array($this, 'custom_add_type'));
public function custom_add_type($types) {
    $types['wpfm_food_product'] = __('Food Product', 'wpfm-online-order');
    return $types;
}
```

and then I am creating a product :

```
$product = new WPFM_Online_Order_Food_Product();
$product->set_name('Test product');
$product->set_slug('test-product');
$product->set_regular_price(10);
$product->save();
$product_id = $product->get_id();
wp_set_object_terms($product_id, 'wpfm_food_product', 'product_type');
```

Anyone can help me with this code or else with the another way.

Comment: [Way to create custom product type](https://webkul.com/blog/create-a-custom-product-type-in-woocommerce/)

Comment: Error is not occuring but I have to create a product with the food product type product.

https://nimb.ws/cjyTVo

In the screenshot you can see that product type is selected as a simple but it would be selected as a food product as we register and create a product.

the select box is selected as a food product

Comment: Refer the link I've sent

Comment: I have allready tried all of the results from google but didn't worked.

Comment: And your refer link is not usable because there is only register the product type. I want to  create a product with the custom product type programmatically.